# Can 4 lines intersect in 2 points?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

Four lines can intersect in at most $\frac{4^{2}-4}{2} = 6$ points. And in fact you can find an example of lines intersecting in 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 and 6 points. All but 2. Obviously there isn't any way how four lines can intersect in two points. **But how to prove it?**

Comment: 2 points is possible in either spherical or hyperbolic geometry.  
Therefore, the parallel line constraints of Euclidean geometry must be involved.  Does a line join the two points?  There is a 3-line, 2 point set-up.  Prove that an extra line adds at least one more point.  Otherwise, no line joins the two points.  Prove that there are other intersection points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prove this by assuming such a construction exists and deriving a contradiction.

Let's pick our two points of intersection for the construction and go from there. Since each has at least two lines passing through it, let us consider one of the lines ($L_1$) going through one point and two of the lines ($L_2, L_3$) going through the other. (If one of the lines happens to be passing through both points, we just pick the other three for the observation.)

Since neither of $L_2$ and $L_3$ intersect with $L_1$, they are both parallel to $L_1$ as well as each other. But since $L_2$ and $L_3$ pass through a common point, they must coincide, thus contradicting the hypothesis that there are 4 unique lines.